# How to prevent extra text while using /tellraw

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm using the following command to ask the nearest player if they want to spend 750 points to open a door.

```
/tellraw @p ["",{"text":"Buy Door: 750","color":"blue","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/scoreboard players set @a door1 2"},"hoverEvent":{"action":"show_text","value":{"text":"","extra":[{"text":"Buy this door for 750 points?","color":"light_purple"}]}}}]
```

The problem is when it runs the command it will make an output, like a command block, but it's completely white. It states:

> Set score of door1 for Player CaolanMC to 2

Is there any way to remove this? Or, must I, find an alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable these messages by turning off the `sendCommandFeedback` gamerule:

```
/gamerule sendCommandFeedback false
```

This will also disable feedback from other commands, so I'd recommend keeping it on while debugging then disabling it before you publish your map.

---

As a sidenote, your command will only work for operators, as normal players cannot run `/scoreboard players set`.

If you want non-operators to be able to use this, you may want to look into [the trigger command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#trigger) and objective type.

Comment: When you say operator do you mean on a server? I plan to use this as a singleplayer adventure map.

Comment: @ExperimentalRocket Anyone able to use operator commands. It'll only work as it currently is if you allow players access to commands.